# Error with a trigger - List<> to AggregateResult

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a problem with the below trigger

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before insert, before update) {
if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore) {

    Aggregateresult result = Database.query('SELECT datev__c FROM Contact WHERE datev__c != NULL ORDER BY datev__c DESC LIMIT 1');

    if (result != null && result.get('datev__c') != null) {
      Decimal datev = (Decimal) result.get('datev__c');

        for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
            datev = datev + 1;
            c.datev__c = datev;
        }
    }
}

if (Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore) {
    for(Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        if(c.Bank_IBAN__c != null && !SEPA_Toolkit.SEPAUtilities.ValidateIBAN(c.Bank_IBAN__c)) {
            c.Bank_IBAN__c.addError('Invalid IBAN. Please check for typos');
        }
    }
}}
```

The trigger saves fine, but when I try and convert a Lead, I get the following error:

> Error: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, ContactTrigger:
>   execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.TypeException: Invalid
>   conversion from runtime type List to AggregateResult
>   Trigger.ContactTrigger: line 8, column 1: [] (System Code)

Could you please help me troubleshoot it?
Thanks!

Comment: Database.query(String str) returns a List. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use an AggregateResult if you are not aggregate the result? Use List instead:

```
List<Contact> result = Database.query('SELECT datev__c FROM Contact WHERE datev__c != NULL ORDER BY datev__c DESC LIMIT 1');

if (!result.isEmpty() && result.size() == 1) {
  Decimal datev = (Decimal) result[0].datev__c;
...
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense! I'm new to Apex, so learning as I go. Thanks for your input.